# Get Orders related to an email address via Ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, contact-form

I'm trying to create a module that creates a JSON collection of  orders from an email entered into a form.

When am email is entered into a field within my form, the on blur event of the email input should trigger orders to be populated in a select box via the JSON received from a controller using AJAX. This is to help the user select a related order.

However upon visiting the URL of the controller **null** is displayed. How can i fix this?

**IndexController.php**

```
public function emailAction()
{
    $customer_email = $_POST["email"];
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email) ; 

    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $neworderjson = array('orderid'=>$order->getIncrementId(), 'email'=>$order->getCustomerEmail(), 'total'=>$order->getBaseGrandTotal(), 'created'=>$order->getCreatedAt());
        $orderjson[] = $neworderjson;
    }
    return $orderjson;
}

public function IndexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($this->emailAction()));
}
```

**form.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <form_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="form"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="form"><title>Fale Conosco</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="form" template="form/form.phtml"/>-->
            <block type="form/index" name="pedido" template="form/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </form_index_index>
</layout>
```

**form.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("contato/index/email")?>" id="contato" method="post">
<p>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</p>
<p>Email:<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" /></p>
<p><label class="required" for="f_f_compra"><em>*</em>About an order?</label></p>
<div class="select"><select class=" required-entry required-entry select" id="f_f_compra" name="f_f_compra">
<option selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
<option value="Sim">Yes</option>
<option value="Não">No</option>
</select></div>
<ul>
<li id="pedido">
<div class="wide"><label class="required" for="pedido"><em>*</em>Order</label><select id="orders"></select></div>
</li>
</ul>
<p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$j = jQuery.noConflict( true );
$j("#email").focus(function() {}).blur(function() {    
    email = $j("#email").val();    
    $j.ajax({url: "/index.php/form", type: "post", data: { email: email }, dataType: "json",success: function(result){
    $j("#orders" ).empty();
    if (result == null) {
      $j('#orders').append($j("").attr("value","N/A").text("No orders found for this email"));
     } else {      $j.each(result, function (index, data) {
        orderstring = result[index]["orderid"] + " - " + result[index]["total"] + " - " + result[index]["created"];
        $j('#orders').append($j("").attr("value",orderstring).text(orderstring));
           })    }
 }});
});
</script>
</p>
```

But I only get the value "null" when entering the page

[image]

Comment: In indexController.php change `public function IndexAction()` to `public function indexAction()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page requires the `$_POST["email"]` variable to be populated so the controller can use that to generate the collection. Either visit with a form or get data using ajax methods (which is what is being done) using POST to see the collection.

To quickly test you can change `$_POST["email"]` to `$_GET["email"]` and visit the url `form/?email=test@test.com` (But an email with an order associated with it) and the page should show some JSON data.

Visit the page with your form.phtml instead this has the email field which can be populated and then the order data will be grabbed via jquery ajax method using post.

To get this working with your form and json being generated from same URL you could replace your IndexAction() function with below maybe:

```
public function IndexAction() {
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->renderLayout();
  if ($_POST["json"] == "y") {
      $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
      $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($this->emailAction()));
  }
}
```

Your ajax request will need to change also so that the controller knows when to return json:

```
data: { email: email, json: "y" }
```

This line is within your .phtml where the ajax request is made for data.

Comment: Yes, that way it works, it shows me the values, but I'd like to get the values ​​when I give a "blur" after filling in the email, but it looks like the form is performing the action before receiving the POST, then it returns null

Comment: So your orders select gets populated with nothing? Are there any console errors?

Comment: I do not even fill in, as soon as I enter the page it already gives me the value "null", the form does not appear.

Comment: You will need to visit the page with that form.phtml that page is just a json endpoint to get data via ajax.

Comment: I'm in form.phtml, it returns that "null", if I comment the lines `$this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
      $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($this->emailAction()));` in the controller it loads the form but does not perform the action

Comment: You need to seperate the form and the json page should be seperate. The form needs to get that data from the /form url and it can't return pure json if theres a form on there. Updated my answer for another quick solution that should give the page 2 functions.

Comment: It is not returning null and is loading the form but is not displaying the required data

Comment: Have you changed the $_GET["email"] back to POST within the controller?

Comment: Yes, i did this

Comment: I mean on the controller? the page should return null now if you visit form?email=email.com&json=y if controller set to POST

Comment: Actually it should return the form sorry. Make sure all _GET are _POST and on the phtml you are using POST and all should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63113/discussion-between-harri-and-gustavo-souza).